Three.js Draco compression by gltf transform
I want to apply draco compression on the scene which is currently present in the scene without downloading. I know we can read a glb or gltf file from local. I want to read the scene currently present.
const saveScene = async (scene) => {
    exporter.parse(
      scene,
      async function (glb) {
        console.log("glbUnit8array = ", glb.Uint8Array);
        const glbfile = await io.readBinary(glb);
        console.log("glbfile = ", glbfile);
        glbfile
          .createExtension(KHRDracoMeshCompression)
          .setRequired(true)
          .setEncoderOptions({
            method: KHRDracoMeshCompression.EncoderMethod.EDGEBREAKER,
            encodeSpeed: 5,
            decodeSpeed: 5,
          });
        await glbfile.transform(weld(), quantize(), dedup());
        console.log("After compression = ", glbfile);

        const binaryData = await io.writeBinary(glbfile);
        console.log(binaryData);
      },
      function (error) {
        console.log("An error happened");
      },
      options
    );
  };

I tried this but not working as expected
